# MySql Connector .NET column not found in join operation

Tags: c#, mysql-connector, mysqldatareader

I'am using the official MySql Driver for ADO.NET and I have problems to query my database.

With the MySQL Workbench tool on my server, my SQL-Query works without any problems.

The Adapter DLL is throwing the following message with the same query:

`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column 'CatPro.CategorieId' in 'on clause'`

The column CategorieId exists definitely.

Perhaps, anyone has experiece with the MySql DataAdapter and a idea to solve this issue.

```
SELECT Pro.Id AS ProductId, 
       Pro.Name AS ProductName, 
       ProInfo.Id AS ProductInfoId ,
       ProInfo.GeneralDescription, 
       Cat.Title AS CategoryTitle  
       FROM Products AS Pro
       LEFT JOIN subproducts AS ProInfo ON Pro.Id = ProInfo.Id
       LEFT JOIN subproductcategories AS CatPro ON ProInfo.Id = CatPro.SubProductId
       LEFT JOIN categories AS Cat ON Cat.Id = CatPro.CategorieId ORDER BY Pro.Id
```

Best regards

Comment: Can you post the entire SQL statement?  You may be using table aliases in your `JOIN` but not in your column sleection.

Comment: Hey, thx for answering. The strange is, this query, runs in the Workbench tool.

Comment: The column `CategorieId` exists in the table subproductcategories, right? Have you tried to use the actual table name instead of the `CatPro` alias?

Comment: Hey, same error.. Unknown column 'subproductcategories.CategorieId' in 'on clause'